# JavaFX Printing in Android

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application running on Android. One of its requirements is to print receipt to a mobile printer (using Bluetooth Technology). Is JavaFX8 Printing API supported for this? If not, is there a java library that supports this kind of functionality? Need help!

Comment: @José Pereda,Sir, do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, Sir, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @jewelsea, do you have any idea regarding this one?

Comment: You should know by now that this is not the way SO works... you don't need to ask the same question all the time and you don't need to address people to answer it. Please, add the code you have tested. Try a small test, use the Printing API and check for yourself if it works or it fails. Then ask or report the issue :)

Comment: @JoséPereda, thank you Sir, Printing API makes sense.

Comment: I mean, try to use the JavaFX8 Printing API and check if it works with the jfxmobile plugin...

Comment: @JoséPereda, I tried it but is says 'NoClassDefoundError' - PrinterService

Comment: Part of JavaFX 8 features like Streams are not supported by the jfxmobile-plugin, as Dalvik VM runs Java 7. Lambdas are supported because of the Retro-Lambda project. Media is also not supported, and as it seems, Printing is not allowed either.

Comment: Hopefully this will be supported in the future! Looking forward for this!